# What causes this type error in a pattern guard for matching list of tuples

Tags: scala, compiler-errors

I have the following code:

```
object foo{
  def splitSeq[Int](in: List[Int], out: List[(Int,Int)] = Nil): List[(Int,Int)] = (in,out) match {
    case (Nil,o) => o
    case (next :: rest, Nil) =>
      splitSeq(rest, List((next,next)))
    case (next :: rest, (start, end) :: accRest) if (end + 1 == next) =>
      splitSeq(rest, (start, next) :: accRest)
    case (next :: rest, acc) =>
      splitSeq(rest, (next,next) :: acc)
  }
}
```

And it produces the following compiler error, which I completely do not understand:

```
~/tmp> scalac test.scala 
test.scala:6: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(1)
 required: String
  case (next :: rest, (start, end) :: accRest) if (end + 1 == next) =>
                                                         ^
one error found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `[Int]` here

```
def splitSeq[Int](in: List[Int], ...
```

It should be just

```
def splitSeq(in: List[Int], ...
```

You declared type parameter `Int` (as if you wrote `def splitSeq[T](in: List[T], ...`) instead of using standard `Int`. And this type parameter `Int` shadowed standard `Int`.

Comment: I want `-xlint:type-parameter-shadow` on by default…